# How do i solve this issue with mySqlWorkbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[mySqlWorkbench screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD96y.png)

description of the problem on mysqlworkbench when I try to start server:

```
2024-03-18 11:09:15 - Start server: ./usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Air-de-Joao.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Air-de-Joao.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 199: /usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Air-de-Joao.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Air-de-Joao.local.err: Permission denied
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Air-de-Joao.local.pid).
```

thanks in advance

I tried few solutions provided by some sources but nothing worked

[used chowned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNeCJ.png)

Comment: Did you read the error? Did you search for solutions for it? Obviously mysql server runs with a user who is not allowed to write into `/usr/local/mysql/data/`

Comment: yes, im not understanding why, since im the admin

Comment: Being an Admin does not auto-guarantee your user can write to any folder :) Try to `chown` that folder recursively with the user the mysql server is set to run with, then restart the service. And read about Linux/Mac user permissions

Comment: I did exactly what you said , correct me if im wrong I put a new picture on the post under the name used chowned, still have the same error.

Comment: This is not a Workbench problem. The problem is how you're running mysqld. It should be run by the `_mysql` user.